XML path into temp table creates a nvarchar column, issues when merging it varchar column
I using SQL Server 2012 and need to use FOR XML PATH to get a comma-separated string for like projects. The query runs and works but when I try to alter #T2, I get an error

String or binary data would be truncated

My code:
select distinct 
    a.WBS1, 
    (select #Team.Team as [text()]
     from #Team
     where #team.WBS1 = a.wbs1
     for xml path('')) as Team 
into #T2from #Team a
order by WBS1 ASC

alter table #T2 
    alter column Team varchar(236)

#Team.Team is defined as varchar(236) after running the code I get #T2.Team is a nvarchar(-1) which I believe is nvarchar(max).
Is there any easy way to convert nvarchar to varchar? Why does #T2.Team end up being a nvarchar if #Team.Team is varchar(236)?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

You aren't defining the data type, you're relying on implicit conversion from xml.

FOR XML always returns nvarchar(max) unless you specify , TYPE in which case you get xml. What's wrong with just using CONVERT(varchar(max), (SELECT ... FOR XML ...) ) Anyway your actual error is clearly because the data is longer than 236 after concatenating.
